# .htaccess Redirect to a page with some GET variables on error

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

I want `.htaccess` to redirect to `index.php` on error, but with submitting some special `GET` variables.

For example, on error 404 I want it to redirect to

```
/index.php?article=404.php
```

I don't know how to do that as I haven't found any good tutorial for it.

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?article=404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?article=403.html
```

It seemed to work for 404 error, but for 403 error it shown:

> ## Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access [...] on
>   this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

How should I do it?

Comment: your htaccess is fine, but understand that it applies to all subfolders as well, and since youre using relative paths, if a user visits `yoursite.com/somefolder/someotherfolder/somepage.php`, instead of being redirected to `yoursite.com/index.php`, they are redirected to `yoursite.com/somefolder/someotherfolder/index.php` if `someotherfolder` does not contain an index.php then you will get a 404.

Comment: in other words, use the full path to index.php in your htaccess and you should be fine

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'll try.

Comment: sorry, not the full path, i meant the full url

Comment: Ah, right... I wondered how Apache would know its the root directory.

Comment: Hmm... Nothing changed, only now when 404 error occurs it changes whole url instead of just showing other file.

Comment: Do I need to give some more info than just url?`

Comment: if you dont want the url changed then you want to look into url-rewriting. error document doesnt rewrite the url it just does a simepl redirect.

Comment: But how do I redirect-url when error occurs?

Comment: i'm not an expert on htaccess, but i would rewrite all urls to a specific php script and then have that php script do the actual redirecting. php can check if the file exisits and then load a given error page if it's not found. thats how i have always done it.

Comment: @Pamblam I was thinking about that. But I was saying that full url does not works for me

Comment: if you don't want to use php, you can add the `-d` or `-f` flags to a rewrite condition to check if a file or directory exists.

Comment: well by your explanation `errorDocument` in your htaccess won't do what you want anyway so I thought we were talking about something else now (url rewriting)